# VBA: Overflow error?

Tags: excel, vba, overflow

My code is designed to test each agent (turtle) with its respective agent (ninjaturtle). It checks for three parameters. However, I keep getting an overflow error. I have converted my d1 and d2 to Long, Int, Variant, but I still keep getting the error. I even tried using cLng, cdbl, etc. but still nothing. The error is found on d2 with the value of 330.552970855757.

The error is thrown in the `d2 = ((Cells(amount * (time - 1) + ninjaturtle + 1, 1).Value))` statement.

```
Sub assesser()
Dim time As Integer
Dim turtle As Integer
Dim ninjaturtle As Integer
Dim amount As Integer
Dim d1 As Variant
Dim d2 As Variant

amount = 20
Columns(15).Clear
Cells(1, 15).Value = "Flock"
For time = 1000 To 2000
    For turtle = 1 To 20
        For ninjaturtle = 1 To 20
        d1 = (Cells(amount * (time - 1) + turtle + 1, 1).Value)
        d2 = ((Cells(amount * (time - 1) + ninjaturtle + 1, 1).Value))
If (Abs(d1 - d2) < 15 _
Or Abs(d1 - d2) > 345) _
And Abs(d1 - d2) < 10 _
And Abs(d1 - d2) < 10 _
Then If IsEmpty(Cells(amount * (time - 1) + turtle + 1, 15).Value) = True Then Cells(amount * (time - 1) + turtle + 1, 15).Value = CStr(Cells(amount * (time - 1) + turtle + 1, 15)) + " " + CStr(Cells(amount * (time - 1) + ninjaturtle + 1, 5)) _
Else Cells(amount * (time - 1) + turtle + 1, 15).Value = CStr(Cells(amount * (time - 1) + turtle + 1, 15)) + ", " + CStr(Cells(amount * (time - 1) + ninjaturtle + 1, 5))

Next ninjaturtle
Next turtle
Next time
Debug.Print (d1)
Debug.Print (d2)

End Sub
```

Comment: Change your `Integer`s  to `Long`s.

Comment: ^^^^ is not your problem, just good advice.

Comment: What line specifically throws the error?

Comment: It might help in the debugging to isolate the time, turtle, and ninjaturtle iterations.  (an aside - your `if isempty()` returns a logical ... no need to check if `=  True'. As coded your effectively saying `If True = True` -- just a thought..

Comment: @ScottCraner That actually fixed it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I tried to declare it as double but the error popped up still
Thank you so much for the replies!

Comment: @Jbowman Thanks for the feedback! I don't come from a coding background so I am definitely not an efficient coder :)

Comment: You never updated any of us about specifically which line was throwing the error, so it's pretty hard to give you a definitive answer, but `Integer` being an signed 16-bit integer type, its maximum value is `2^15-1`, i.e. 32,767 - trying to assign it to anything greater than that will throw that exact error. There's no reason to not use `Long` instead, i.e. a 32-bit signed integer type with a maximum value of `2^31-1`, i.e. well above 2 billion.. much harder to overflow :)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Sorry! It's the 
       d2 = ((Cells(amount * (time - 1) + ninjaturtle + 1, 1).Value))
but the first answer fixed it (changing my int to long)